# javascript eventListener doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, node.js

app.js

```
const statesElement = document.querySelector('#states');
const infoElement = document.querySelector("#info");

function setUSSates(states) {
    states.forEach((state) => {
        const optionElement = document.createElement('option');
        optionElement.setAttribute('value', state.name);
        optionElement.textContent = state.name;
        statesElement.append(optionElement);

        optionElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert(state);
        });
    });
}

async function getUSStates() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/states');
    const states = await response.json();
    setUSSates(states);
}

getUSStates();
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');

const getUSStates = require("./getUSStates");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/api/states', async (req, res) => {
    const states = await getUSStates();
    res.json(states);
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>US States</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ez-css.now.sh">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select a US State</h1>
    <select id="states"></select>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's simple node.js code.
I wanted to do something when they pick option on dropdown menu. but when I click option it doesn't do anything. like I don't get alert.
I'm just following one youtuber and It's exactly the same I think.
But mine doesn't work.

Comment: can you add the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: You cannot add event listeners in node. This cannot be node

Comment: You should delegate. This needs to live in a web page

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: It does not appear that the `option` elements fire click events.  You will get the `change` event in the parent `select` tag when an option is selected.

Comment: Ok I added some more code. I have the relevant HTML. and sorry It's front-end javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your event listener to the select element instead of the options element.

```js
const statesElement = document.querySelector('#states');
const infoElement = document.querySelector("#info");

function setUSSates(states) {
    states.forEach((state) => {
        const optionElement = document.createElement('option');
        optionElement.setAttribute('value', state.name);
        optionElement.textContent = state.name;
        
        statesElement.append(optionElement);
    });
  
    statesElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      console.log('clicked: ', e.target.value);                                          infoElement.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  })
}



setUSSates([
{ name: 'New York' },
{ name: 'Nevada' },
{ name: 'California' }
]);
```

```html
<select id="states"></select>

<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Don't know if the server part is the problem, I fixed an error that was preventing the code from working as expected.

Comment: I have States data with json format. so I actually wanted to add 
        infoElement.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</pre>`  this in the eventlistener in for loop. is there any other way i could do it?